# Unpacking 'Non-Standard' Boot.img Problems for 64 Bit Device

Tags: samsung, 5.1-lollipop, boot, kernel

This is in relation to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/xcover-3-sm-g388f-root-5-1-1-t3365125/page4) XDA thread and [my thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/technical-bypassing-restrictions-t3452479) on xda. This is a [cross post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/samsung-unpacking-standard-boot-img-t3457265) from XDA, trying my luck on here. I also asked this question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401168/unpacking-non-standard-boot-img-problems-for-64-bit-device), but am covering all my  bases and trying my luck here as well.

Device specs, just in case someone asks

**Device Specifications:**

- **Current Android Version:** Android Lollipop 5.1.1
- **Chipset:** Marvell Armada PXA1908 (Note: Due to this being a rarely used chip, the CF-Auto root won't work)
- **Custom Recovery Status:** TWRP 3.0.2-0 (Not working with lollipop)
- **Root Status** (This is technically why I am here):  Android KitKat 4.4.4 (Root), Android Lollipop 5.1.1 (NO ROOT Yet)
- **ARMv8 64-bit**

Now let's get into my steps up to the point and then my problem.

Note: In the kernel readme it states to use the toolchain 4.8 but when I use it, it complains of not being able to find gcc. Also in the read me it states *"get Toolchain download and install arm-eabi-4.8 toolchain for ARM EABI.(64bit)"* and when [reading up](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html#syt) on it, it says to use aarch64 for ARM 64 Bit devices.

Device Source Code can be found at [Here](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=F&searchValue=g388f)

```
cd ~/android
export CROSS_COMPILE=~/android/ndk/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
cd ~/android/kernel
make ARCH=arm64 pxa1908_xcover3lte_eur_defconfig
make ARCH=arm64
```

This outputs: Image, Image.gz, .dts and .dtb files.

Where's the kernel readme (I believe this hasn't been update since kitkat) says the output will be,
    - Kernel : Kernel/arch/arm/boot/zImage
    - module : Kernel/drivers/*/*.ko
Note: when trying to compile with the 32- bit ARM toolchain it fails,  as the config is found in arm64, wheres other configs are found in arm.

So know I have a kernel (Image or Image.gz), and some .dts and .dtb files. Now to unpack boot.img, **this is where problems occur**. When trying to use tools like abootimg or the various different versions of unmkbootimg, they complain about non-standard boot.img.

[image: Non-Standard boot.img]

or

[image: Non-Standard boot.img 2]

While also try saving it as a zImage when its meant to be a Image.gz, or they extract it without throwing any errors, but when looking at the extracted files with a hex editor, it is all 00 throughout the files, therefore a useless file.

So therefor I tried manually unpacking with a hex editor and managed to get the kernel. Left is my Compiled and Right is the hex version.

[image: Kernels, Hex and Compiled]

Notice the difference in size, is this because the kernel in boot.img is stripped of its debugging items while mine isn't? If so I should look up on how to fix that.

But I am **having troubles trying to extract the ramdisk** via hex. 
So is anyone able to Teach/Help me extract the boot.img properly (with tools like unmkbootimg or with a hex editor)

I have attached necessary files if you want to have a look at them yourself.
Files: [Samsung xCover3 Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5mtquWAP3MZjJQay1ERFprbnM/view?usp=sharing)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Numerous trial and error, I finally managed to output ramdisk.gz.cpio, this was from starting at the correct ramdisk hex .gz area, search 00 00 00 00 1F 8B, narrows it down to 2 sections, kernel (Image.gz) and ramdisk.gz.cpio. So for the ramdisk I started from 1F 8B and went all the way to the end of the document ( I was before stoping to early, therefor corrupting it).